# Org - show checkboxes in Agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there anyway to show outline with its [checkboxes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) in Org Agenda views like this?

```
** TODO Checkboxes [1/3]
   SCHEDULED: <2014-11-28 Fri 12:00>
- [X] Wash cloths
- [ ] Buy milk
- [ ] Wash dishes
```

Currently, my Agenda can only show its title outline:

```
...
Friday     28 November 2014
               1:12...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
               8:00...... ----------------
              10:00...... ----------------
  Todo:       12:00...... Scheduled: TODO Checkboxes [1/3]
              12:00...... ----------------
              14:00...... ----------------
              16:00...... ----------------
              18:00...... ----------------
              20:00...... ----------------
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

View the EntryText in Agenda view by pressing "v" then "E".

You cannot interact with the checkboxes, but you can view them this way.

Alternatively, "follow mode" (press "F" in Agenda view) might also help you get what you want. The checkboxes won't be in the Agenda, but you have easy access to them.

Comment: Or `Agenda Previews`: https://github.com/alphapapa/unpackaged.el#agenda-previews